# Nodejs Create User endpoint, how to optimize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, endpoint

So I have a NodeJS project where I have an endpoint where I create an User. I'm using Mongoose to create the User Model to save it to a MongoDB database. Here's my code:

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

exports.createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error = new Error("Validación incorrecta");
    error.statusCode = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const role = req.body.role;
  //creandolo en la base de datos
  const user = new User({
    userName: userName,
    password: password,
    role: role
  });
  try {
    await user.save(); //guardando en bd
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Usuario creado con exito!",
      user: user
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

I import my user model file and use body-parser as well. I already set an endpoint with a post request, and I tested this code on Postman and it works. 
I'm a beginner, I just watched a NodeJS course in Udemy and I'm following the code pattern I saw there. My question goes to the fact I have to req.body parse every field (username, pass, role) and then create a new User with same fields to create it directly in the database, and for scalability reasons I think this would be a problem, since I'm planning to add more models to my database with a lot of fields.

Comment: Just do `new User(req.body)` instead

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. :3